# Use PHP to multiply dropdown value(product) with input field value(quantity) to get and print the result on HTML

Tags: php, html

I am a new student for PHP and HTML development. I have a question to use PHP to multiply dropdown value(product) with input field value(quantity) to get total price and print the message on HTML. Also, I need information including user name, phone number, and address. 
Here are my codes:

```
<html>

<body>

<form>

<form method="post">

product:
<select name="product" input type="int" id="product" option value="<?php echo $product; ?>"> 
<option>Select Item</option>
<option value="3">apple</option>
<option value="2">banana</option>
<option value="4">pear</option>
<option value="8">peach</option>
<option value="8">grape</option>
<option value="2">watermelon</option>
<option value="4">pineapple</option>
<option value="3">mandarin</option>
<option value="5">mango</option>
<option value="5">plum</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

quantity: 
<input type="int" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>">
<br>
<br>
user name: <input type="text" name="username" /> <br><br>
phone number: <input type="int" name="phonenumber" /> <br><br>
address: <input type="text" name="address" /> <br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $product = $_POST['product']; 
       $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
       echo $product*$quantity;
       }

?>
```

Anyone could help me to solve the issue? Much appreciate. Also, it requires to record if the number of ordered product doesn't exceed the available quantity of the product in database, then print a message on the web page including a successful confirmation about the user's order and the total price of this order.

Comment: I think you need to use JavaScript or Jquery

Comment: You have two `<form>` tags, which results in unspecified behaviour. Remove the duplicate, and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
<?php 
// Check if form was submitted
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $product = $_POST['product']; 
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $calculation = $product * $quantity;
    echo "Product x Quantity = " . $calculation;
    echo "<br>"; // line break
    echo "Username: " . $_POST['username'];
    echo "<br>"; // line break
    echo "Phone Number: " . $_POST['phonenumber'];
    echo "<br>"; // line break
    echo "Address: " . $_POST['address'];

}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="product" id="product">
        <option>Select Item</option>
        <option value="3">apple</option>
        <option value="2">banana</option>
        <option value="4">pear</option>
        <option value="8">peach</option>
        <option value="8">grape</option>
        <option value="2">watermelon</option>
        <option value="4">pineapple</option>
        <option value="3">mandarin</option>
        <option value="5">mango</option>
        <option value="5">plum</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br><br>
    Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phonenumber"><br><br>
    Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

So, when the form is submitted, it will echo the values that were entered in the fields.

PS: The select tag does not need an `input type`, `option value` attributes. I'll recommend taking a look at this [course](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

Comment: Thanks Samuel, I have got the answer although it misses the input field for quantity.